# Can I pass in an object into a SOAP API request

Tags: api, ssis, postman

The object required contains a string. When I pass in the string I receive an error. Is there a way to build up an object using XML in a SOAP request. According to my knowledge, SOAP requests have to be in XML format.

Comment: I'm using SSIS to process my SOAP request

Comment: People might need more context/examples to help with this